# Superscrollorama, TweenMax Make an Animation play and after that resume scrolling

Tags: jquery, gsap

Is there a way to let the user scroll to a certain point, 
an element fades in, 
after that an animation (X2) is played (without user input) 
and after that scrolling triggers further animations, but those can only be triggered if the animation(X2) has played through.

```
var controller = $.superscrollorama({
            triggerAtCenter: false
        });
            // set duration, in pixels scrolled, for pinned element
                var pinDur = 2800;

                // create animation timeline for pinned element
                var pinAnimations = new TimelineLite();
                pinAnimations
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to($('#mouse_walk'), 5, {css:{opacity: 1},
                            onComplete: function(){
                                $( "#mouse_walk, #mouse_walk img" ).stop().animate( {height: '977px', width: '1080px', left: '49.5%', top:'370px'}, 200, function(){
                                    $( "#mouse_walk, #mouse_walk img" ).stop().animate( {height: '944px', width: '1044px', left: '50%', top:'380px'}, 200, function(){
                                        $( "#mouse_walk, #mouse_walk img" ).stop().animate( {height: '995px', width: '1100px', left: '49.3%', top:'360px'}, 200, function(){
                                            $( "#mouse_walk, #mouse_walk img" ).stop().animate( {height: '944px', width: '1044px', left: '50%', top:'380px'}, 200, function(){
                                                setTimeout(function() {
                                                      $( "#mouse_walk, #mouse_walk img" ).stop().animate( {height: '977px', width: '1080px', left: '49.5%', top:'370px'}, 200, function(){
                                                          $( "#mouse_walk, #mouse_walk img" ).stop().animate( {height: '944px', width: '1044px', left: '50%', top:'380px'}, 200, function(){
                                                              $( "#mouse_walk, #mouse_walk img" ).stop().animate( {height: '995px', width: '1100px', left: '49.3%', top:'360px'}, 200, function(){
                                                                  $( "#mouse_walk, #mouse_walk img" ).stop().animate( {height: '944px', width: '1044px', left: '50%', top:'380px'}, 200, function(){
                                                                    })
                                                                })
                                                            })
                                                        })
                                                    }, 800);
                                                    })
                                                })
                                            })
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        ])
                    .append([
                        TweenMax.to( $('#mouse_walk_hell'), 5, {css:{opacity: '1'}})
                    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

This really seems overly complicated.

My thought process on this you have a pin that does your initial animation.

onComplete of that animation you directly add the tween you want to happen?

You can nest another timelineLight inside of the onComplete method so you can sequence those animations without having that huge nested group of JQuery animation.

I also highly recommend not to mix greensock and JQuery animations together, they have caused a nightmare for me.